Firefox keeps muting sites
I don't want Firefox to autoplay sound on every video I scroll by, but I would like it when I click play on one. I have to keep going into the audio settings & clicking to unmute. Not that big of a deal, but can be a hassle. YouTube, Twitter, Instagram etc. Seems to be just an Ubuntu problem. Doesn't happen on any of my Windows machines.

Firefox has a setting for it: Settings/Privacy & Security/Permissions/Autoplay.

Autoplay will play all videos as I scroll down along with audio. I do not want this. Only when I click to play. This is what usually has been happening. Since I did a fresh install of 24.04, on the occasional ones I do want to watch, it plays, but no sound. I have to bring up the audio settings. There will sometimes be multiple videos from the same site, some muted, some not. I have to find the one I want & click it to get sound.

Autoplay in Firefox, at least the one I use, does not play both video and audio, unless configured that way. You should check out the Autoplay settings I've mentioned in a comment above:
Settings/Privacy & Security/Permissions/Autoplay

There are tree options available.

